# cordova-plugin-facebook4 - Blank Dialog with "Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again"

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

**Screenshot**

[image: Image of Error]

**Issue**

`facebookConnectPlugin.login` dialog shows error in screenshot. The only thing that can be done is selection of the X close-out button which results in the following error:

errorCode: "4201"
errorMessage: "User cancelled dialog"
loginError @ facebook.js:13

What are we doing wrong?

**Plugin version, OS, devices, etc**

8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.0.0
Android 7.1.1
OSX 10.13.6

**code**

https://github.com/lightbeard/reproduce-fb-login

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {

  var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
  }

  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
    function loginError (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: According the last comment in https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/499 it's suggested to review the Facebook App config for Android. In you config.xml you've got com.example.hello do you have that package name in your Facebook config too? P.S.: peterpeterparker here

Comment: That was it, the android platform was not added in https://developers.facebook.com/apps - the plugin worked fine for iOS, so I didn't think there was an issue on the fb side. Thanks for your help, if you add an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awesome, nice to hear it worked out :)

To solves the error OP had to do the two following things:

1. Adding the missing configuration for `cordova-android` >= 7 in `config.xml` Like described in the documentation https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md

   ```
   <config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
       <string name="fb_app_id">123456789</string>
       <string name="fb_app_name">myApplication</string>
   </config-file>
   ```
2. Adding an Android platform to the corresponding Facebook App in his/her Facebook developper console https://developers.facebook.com/apps